# Print a new <tr> each time & "N" number of elements inside it, for a total quantity of "Q"

Tags: php, html, algorithm, loops, html-table

i have a variable Q,
i want to print "cat" (or whatever) Q times in HTML table rows, only each row of the HTML table can contain maximum of 5 cats. 
like if Q <= 5 then i want to print a single `<tr>`.
& if Q = 10;
then i want to print 2 rows each containing 5 cats.

can someone help me here?

I'm using php as the programming language and HTML.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a go at writing the code yourself, and we'll help you make it work

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to decide the chunk(no. of times) for each row and repeat a string using [`str_repeat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) the chunk size times to achieve your goal.

```
<?php

$times = 12;
$limit_for_each_row = 5;
$string = "Cat";

echo "<table>";
foreach(array_chunk(range(1,$times),$limit_for_each_row) as $chunk){
    echo "<tr>" . str_repeat("<td>$string</td>",count($chunk)) . "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/EWgHh

Comment: Appreciate your help <3

Answer (score 0):

May following code will help you to achieve requested output:

```
<?php
$print_label = "meow";
$q = 15;
$steps = 5;

echo "<table>";
for($i=1;$i<=ceil($q/$steps);$i++) :
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=1;$j<=$steps;$j++) :
        echo "<td>".$print_label."</td>";
    endfor;
    echo "</tr>";
endfor;
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is by using [`array_fill`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill) to make an array of `$q` copies of the word; [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split that into the maximum number of words per row; and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to put all the words in each chunk together into a row:

```
$word = "cat";
$q = 13;
$row_max = 5;
$words = array_fill(0, $q, $word);
$chunks = array_chunk($words, $row_max);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $chunk) . '</td></tr>' . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>cat</td><td>cat</td><td>cat</td><td>cat</td><td>cat</td></tr>
<tr><td>cat</td><td>cat</td><td>cat</td><td>cat</td><td>cat</td></tr>
<tr><td>cat</td><td>cat</td><td>cat</td></tr>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/g8Eai)